# Multiple Parent Hierarchical Transformations OpenGL

Tags: opengl, transformation, hierarchical

I would like to transform a linkage of bars (cuboids that are linked together via joints), using transformation matrices in OpenGL.  If the linkage structure is a tree, i can transform it fine, by simply fixing one part, setting it as the root of the tree, then for each part, the transformation matrix of that part is its own local transformation multiplied by the transformation matrices of its ancestors up to the root.

However, i don't know how to do this, if the linkage structure is a graph that has cycles.  This would mean that a node might have multiple parents, how can i describe the transformation matrix of a node that has multiple parents in terms of all of its ancestors in the graph up to the root?